# SAGE: Finding the Automorphism Group of a Permutation Group

Tags: sage

I'd like to compute the automorphism group of a permutation group in Sage. For example, in GAP I can compute the following:

```
grp := Group([ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ]);
aut := AutomorphismGroup(grp);

Group( [ GroupHomomorphismByImages( Group( [ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ] ), Group( [ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ] ), Pcgs(
    [ (2,3,5,4), (2,5)(3,4), (1,2,3,4,5) ]), [ (2,3,5,4), (2,5)(3,4), (1,3,5,2,4) ] ),
  GroupHomomorphismByImages( Group( [ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ] ), Group( [ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ] ), Pcgs(
    [ (2,3,5,4), (2,5)(3,4), (1,2,3,4,5) ]), [ (2,3,5,4), (2,5)(3,4), (1,5,4,3,2) ] ),
  GroupHomomorphismByImages( Group( [ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ] ), Group( [ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ] ), Pcgs(
    [ (2,3,5,4), (2,5)(3,4), (1,2,3,4,5) ]), [ (1,2,4,3), (1,4)(2,3), (1,2,3,4,5) ] ) ] )
```

After some searching, it appears there's no function written in Sage to do this; however, I stumbled across this question (and answer) on this site: [SAGE: Automorphism group of finite abelian group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672107/sage-automorphism-group-of-finite-abelian-group)

The suggestion is to do the following:

```
grp = PermutationGroup([ '(1,2,3,4,5)', '(1,2,4,3)' ])
H = gap(grp).AutomorphismGroup()
PermutationGroup(gap_group = H.AsPermGroup())

Permutation Group with generators [(2,3,5,4), (2,5)(3,4), (1,5,4,3,2)]
```

I cannot get this code to work. I'm running Sage 8.9 on Windows 10. When I put the above code into Sage Cell Server (https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) it works just fine. When I run it in my installed copy, I get the following error output:

```
RuntimeError: Gap produced error output
Error, Variable: 'AsPermGroup' must have a value

   executing __SAGE_LAST__:="__SAGE_LAST__";;AsPermGroup(\$sage3);;
```

I really need to get this to work. Is this an issue with Sage 8.9 via Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't tons of Sage gurus using Windows, but some of those who know a bit more about this tend to lurk at ask.sagemath.org, so I suggest you try that.  It's weird that it works on the Sage cell server - can you post a link to the "shared" permalink for yours?

Comment: I posted an answer on how I found a way to get the same result on Windows and why I think the Sage cell server works with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to compute this in Sage 8.9 (on Windows) by invoking GAP and using the 'NiceObject' command as follows:

```
sage: grp = PermutationGroup([ '(1,2,3,4,5)', '(1,2,4,3)' ])
sage: G_gap = gap(grp)
sage: gap.eval("aut := SmallGeneratingSet(NiceObject(AutomorphismGroup({})))".format(G_gap))
sage: A_gen = gap.new("aut")
sage: aut = PermutationGroup(A_gen)
sage: aut
Permutation Group with generators [(1,5,4,3,2), (2,3,5,4)]
```

This will work in Linux and Mac versions of Sage as well. I believe the issue above is that the Windows version of Sage doesn't include the optional gap packages, which includes the gap package 'Sonata' which has the function 'AsPermGroup'. The Sage Cell Server has these optional packages installed. I couldn't figure out how to install these optional packages in the Windows distribution of Sage, but the above code works just fine for me. Hopefully this helps someone else out.

Comment: That seems pretty reasonable of a reason, and I do remember something of this kind.  Thanks for providing the answer!  Yes, the optional gap packages are necessary for a lot of stuff.